# How can you auto fill city, state and country form fields based on IP address?

Tags: forms, geolocation, ip

What's the easiest way to get a visitors city, state and country based on their IP address and fill it into a form field?

For example I have a basic form field:

`<input type="text" name="city" value="*AUTOFILL CITY HERE*" />`

Instead of having them fill this information in I'd like to just hide the form field and have it autofill based on their IP.

Comment: which platform(language) you will used??

Comment: Mostly PHP. Form is obviously in html/css. Ideally would like something that just auto fills the city/state/country in the input field which would probably require some javascript?

Comment: I think I figured it out with something like this:

<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
 
<br>Country Code:
<script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_country_code());</script>

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution for you which is in the form of html, javascript and jquery.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Client side IP geolocation using <a href="http://ipinfo.io">ipinfo.io</a></h3>

<hr/>
<div id="ip"></div>
<div id="address"></div>
<hr/>Full response: <pre id="details"></pre>
<input type="text" value="" id="city" />
<script type="text/javascript">

$.get("https://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
    $("#city").html(response.city);
    document.getElementById('city').value = response.city;
}, "jsonp");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

City is filled in automatically, and using the same process you can display the State, as well as the Country, of your visitors.